# Serialize list of a specific field of Many To Many relation in Django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

What I want is to have a list of a specific field from a ManyToMany relation instead of a list of dictionaries that the field is in.

For example, with the following code, I get the result shown below

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Bar(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, related_name="foos")


# serializers.py

from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer 
from .models import Bar, Foo

class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ("title",)

class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("title", "bars")


# views.py

from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .serializers import FooSerializer
from .models import Foo

class FooAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Foo.objects.prefetch_related("bars")
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

Result:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "foo 1",
        "bars": [
            { "title": "bar title 1" },
            { "title": "bar title 2" },
            { "title": "bar title 3" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "foo 2",
        "bars": [
            { "title": "bar title 4" },
            { "title": "bar title 5" },
            { "title": "bar title 6" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "foo 3",
        "bars": [
            { "title": "bar title 7" },
            { "title": "bar title 8" },
            { "title": "bar title 9" }
        ]
    }
]
```

But what I want is a list of titles for the `bars` field.

Desired Result:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "foo 1",
    "bars": ["bar title 1", "bar title 2", "bar title 3"]
  },
  {
    "title": "foo 2",
    "bars": ["bar title 4", "bar title 5", "bar title 6"]
  },
  {
    "title": "foo 3",
    "bars": ["bar title 7", "bar title 8", "bar title 9"]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do this without having to override Django methods?

Comment: You can use SerializerMethodField. Checkout This [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: @pi3o1416 As I commented for `lord stock`'s answer, the problem with this solution is that it hits a query for bars for each instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way with [serializerMethod field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bars = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("title", "bars")

    def get_bars(self, instance):
        return instance.bars.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem with this solution is that it hits a query for bars for each instance, so not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Amrez 
bars = BarSerializer(many=True)
for this line for each instance there will be query as well

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor Actually no! if you use `prefetch_related`, it'll run just one query for all the bars.

Comment: @Amrez if you use prefetch_related you can use 
def get_bars(self, instance):
        return instance.bars.values_list('title', flat=True)

this method if will not run that query again. since prefetch_related already done that.

or I can give you another idea you can use constructor of serializer

Comment: @ShofiullahBabor Every way I tested it, more than one query was hit. But thanks anyway, and sorry for the late respond.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ("title",)

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only= True)

    def get_bars(self,obj):
        bars = [i.title for i in obj.bars.all()]
        return bars

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("title", "bars")
```

NOTE -  this solution appends Bars of specific Foos in the list, not hits query

#### Another solution

You can create @property in model and use it in a serializer like this...

#### models.py

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, related_name="foos")

    @property
    def get_bars(self):
        return [i.title for i in self.bars.all()]
```

#### serializers.py

```py
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("title", "get_bars")
```

#### Output with both way

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have come up with so far is to override the `to_representation` method in serializer class and return the wanted field's value as final representation of the object.

The problem with other solutions was that, it would cause more than one query to be hit for the bars.

```py
# serializer.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Bar, Foo

class BarSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.title

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ("title", "bars")
```